# Creating DB in Python return errors (1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Creating database return error.
Also even removing/adding quotes/backtics also return error.

My Python code:

> ```
> generateUUID = uuid.uuid4()
> newUUID = str(generateUUID)
> cursor.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE `{newUUID}`")
> ```

Tried ways:

```
Without quotes
```

> `cursor.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE {newUUID}")`

```
 With quotes
```

> `cursor.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE '{newUUID}' ")`

which both return errors:

> 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
> that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
> to use near ''77d1247c-537e-4284-947c-1770bbf26146'' at line 1

Comment: Append a semicolon to your SQL statement. Use the first version (with backticks `\``).

Comment: cursor.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE `{'newUUID'}`")

like that?

Comment: Nope, use the method in your first attempt: `cursor.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE \`{newUUID}\`;")`.